# how to do a select * in jython and get the result

Tags: sql, jython

how to do a `select * from table` in jython and get the result for each row into a list or string. 
i know how to do for select counmn_name1 ,column_name2 from table1 but not able to figure out for select *

Please suggest .thanks

Comment: Using `select *` makes your code liable to break when someone adds columns to the schema later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JDBC then you can use JDBC ResultSetMetaData interface:

```
    rs = c.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM a_tmp_table")
    while (rs.next()):
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData()
        print('columnCnt: %d' % (rsmd.getColumnCount()))
        for i in range(rsmd.getColumnCount()):
            print(rs.getString(i + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [zxJDBC](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html) (comes with Jython) then you can follow the cross-implementation [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) protocol to execute queries and retrieve results.